# How can I place a text hyperlink in a clickable div tag such that only the hyperlink is triggered when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have some clickable divs which contain text. In some cases the text itself is a hyperlink.

I would like to generally be able to click on the div and have it trigger its onclick action, however when clicking directly on a hyperlink, I only want the hyperlink action to trigger and not the div onclick action.

The below sample code illustrates the issue - when clicking the hyperlink, the div turns red (onclick) AND google opens in a new tab. In this scenario I only want google opened in a new tab. When clicking anywhere else on the div the color should change to red.

Thanks in advance,

Dennis

```
<div id="myDiv" style="height:60px;width:200px;border:solid" onclick="this.style.color='red';"}>
This is NOT a hyperlink.
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">This IS a hyperlink.</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener), listening on the `click` event, and check the `target` rather than the `currentTarget`.

You just need to check that the `target` (the actual element that was clicked) is not an `a` tag. In such a case, you would change the color of the `currentTarget` (the element the event listener is applied to).

Here is a working snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('a')) {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add('color');
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid;
}

.color {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
This is NOT a hyperlink.
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">This IS a hyperlink.</a>
</div>
```

Note - I've adapted the code to use proper CSS rather than inline styles. This has a lot more mileage in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you either need a custom event listener for click on anchor elements, using [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture), or to enhance the onclick listener for your div to be smart enough to inspect the [event target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Something like

```js
if (event.target === this) {
  this.style.color='red';
}
```